# Why is my Peace lily dying?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, indoors, containers, peace-lily

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

Help! My peace lily is dying. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with it? I just don't understand why the leaves continue to darken around the edge and then fall off. I only water it once a week. I let the water sit out a day or two before watering. What could be causing this?

---

Thank you for the welcome. I have not changed anything with the plant. I've been watering it the same way since I have gotten it. I received the plant at my grandmother's funeral about 9 months ago.

The pot is not a self watering pot. I water it myself once a week. I water the plant every Monday. The plant usually began to wilt a little before watering it.  I guess I will take the plant out of the pot and replant it to see if it's root rot.

---

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Here's my other peace lily. It isn't in as bad of shape but it's not doing well either. I just trimmed all the dead leaves off it last week and I woke up today to more dead leaves. The tip of brand new leafs brown. Then on other leaves they turn brown and it's like it eats the leaf until I have to cut it. New leaves are growing but I'm constantly cutting off the dead ones.
Do you guys think a smaller pot would help?
As far as the pot they are in now goes, the bottom part of the pot is for extra water to go into if there's any. You can also water the plant by putting the water in the bottom part of the pot and the Plant should suck the water up.
However I water from the top and leave the bottom attached incase I ever over water there not a mess.
I'll attach more photos of my other plant

---

Here's another photo of the leaf yellowing and browning.

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 2):

Brown and yellow tips and edges on the leaves could be a sign of excess fertilization.  One quarter strength houseplant fertilizer is sufficient once every two or three months.
It could also be due to a mineral buildup.   Hard tap water or water treated with a softener can cause mineral and salt buildup around the roots and suffocate the plant.  If that is the case, flush the plant container with bottled water and continue to use bottled water to feed the plant.
As for a smaller pot, peace lilies don't mind a little crowding, but please ensure your plant does not get rootbound.  Severely rootbound plants will not be able to absorb water efficiently.